# What's the difference between "Company Alerts" and "Company Alerts"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, email, alerts

(Note: The title is intentional)

On the "Edit profile" page, in the "Edit email settings" tab, there are two settings for turning on/off "Company Alerts":

[image: Image of "Edit email settings" page with two settings called "Company Alerts" highlighted]

One is just a simple on/off toggle, while the other one has the option to turn off or set to "Weekly" a.k.a turn on, but set to weekly.

Can the settings be merged and additional options (<kbd>Off</kbd> <kbd>Daily</kbd> <kbd>Weekly</kbd> <kbd>Monthly</kbd>) be added?

Another point to note is that it's impossible to turn off "Company Alerts" (from the first setting in the screenshot). Switching it off and reloading the page only switches it on again. Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: Looks like an option connected to Jobs which was discontinued and no longer exists.

Comment: @Ramhound or the new ["Companies"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) (SO Talents) submenu, replacing SO Jobs.

Comment: One is for content from companies you follow, and the other is for content from companies you follow.  Isn't it obvious?

Comment: @RyanM and one is called “Company Alerts” but the other is called “Company Alerts”

Comment: Since it's in review, it's most likely some kind of a bug.

Comment: This is indeed a bug. The team is working on a fix.

Comment: Thanks, @Rosie. Could you also take a look at this: [Company Alerts cannot be turned on/off anywhere except Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379514/company-alerts-cannot-be-turned-on-off-anywhere-except-stack-overflow)?

Comment: @Justin thank you that other one looks like a bug as well so I've marked as status review so it can get sent to the correct team for triage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two is that one of them doesn't exist now... :)

---

The first buggy setting has now been removed:

[image]

However, the second setting (highlighted above) is also buggy as described in [Company Alerts cannot be turned on/off anywhere except Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379514/company-alerts-cannot-be-turned-on-off-anywhere-except-stack-overflow)