# Company Alerts cannot be turned on/off anywhere except Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, email, alerts

This question stems from my previous post, [What's the difference between "Company Alerts" and "Company Alerts"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377967/whats-the-difference-between-company-alerts-and-company-alerts)

Currently, I can turn on/off my Company Alerts (i.e., set to <kbd>Weekly</kbd>) *only* from Stack Overflow:

[image: Image of "Edit email settings" page with a setting called "Company Alerts" highlighted]

When it's turned *on* from Stack Overflow, it doesn't reflect in any of my other profiles; it's always turned off.

When it's turned *off* from Stack Overflow, turning it *on* is also not possible from any other site. Reloading the page just turns it off again.

Here's a GIF showing what I mean (tested on Super User):

[image: GIF showing the non-functional Company Alerts setting: turning it on and reloading the page turns it off again]

Changing my settings from Stack Overflow should affect all the other sites I'm a member of, as mentioned in the settings itself:

[image: Text in email settings which says "This setting affects" all the sites one is a member of]

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woops, looks like in fixing the original bug the setting was accidentally leaked to network sites. Network sites don't load the necessary JavaScript needed to support the Company Pages feature, so when you'd toggle the setting it wouldn't get saved because there was no JavaScript to actually persist the setting.

Since the Company Pages feature only lives on Stack Overflow, we've removed the setting from network sites and kept it only on SO.